# error in fragment class (android studio)

Tags: java

in the logcat in android studio error is been shown

```
 @Override public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);

  }
```

in the logcat it is shown that the error is in return inflater.inflate(........ 
My app is being stopped by this can somebody please help me in correcting the code

Comment: Please add stacktrace as this shows why it crashes and the layout fragmentlayout

Comment: show us your fragmentlayout.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
return v;}
```

> Try this it will solve your error.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is still not working.

Comment: Delete the line super.onCreateView(------);

Comment: Check your layout file also